# Como cambiar el color a una celda html desde un JS

Tags: javascript, html

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, requiero de su ayuda con una duda, tengo este html:

```
<td>{{data.macEntra}}</td>
<td>{{data.macSale}}</td>
<td>{{data.paquetes}}</td>
<td>{{data.perfil}}</td>
<td>{{data.ciudad}}</td>
<td>{{data.proceso}}</td>
<td>{{data.accion}}</td>
<td id="prueba">{{data.horagestion}}</td>   
<td>{{data.producto}}</td>
<td>{{data.tipoEquipo}}</td>
<td>{{data.remite}}</td>
```

Y tengo otro archivo en JS en el cual hay una validación del tiempo y cuando se cumple una condición necesito cambiar el color al fondo del `<td id="prueba">{{data.horagestion}}</td>` pero no se como hacerlo.

Este es el codigo en el JS:

```
            TV.forEach( function(valor, indice) 
        {
             var diferencia=new Date(js_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss())-new Date(TV[indice]);


            if (diferencia > 900000) 
            {
                console.log("Alerta!");

            }
        });
```

Alguien que me pueda orientar le agradecería.

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Estás utilizando Angular o algún framework? Por favor comparte tu código JS para poder ayudarte. ¿Bajo que condición necesitas cambiarlo? Es importante que seas mas detallado cuando preguntes para poder darle una solución a tu problema.

Comment: Mucha gracias Miguel por tu observación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar el color tiene ante una condición, puedes usar javascript. En mi caso, cambia cuando apreto un boton, pero puedes hacer lo mismo en tu validación. La sentencia q lo cambia es:

```
  document.getElementById('prueba').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

```js
  function cambiarColor(){
    document.getElementById('prueba').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
```

```css
td{border:solid 1px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>{{data.accion}}</td>
    <td id="prueba">{{data.horagestion}}</td>   
    <td>{{data.producto}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="cambiarColor();">Cambiar color</button>
```

Comment: Apoyo esta respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, coloque la linea que me indicas en la validación y no me funciona. Este es el código en mi JS:             TV.forEach( function(valor, indice) 
            {
                 var diferencia=new Date(js_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss())-new Date(TV[indice]);


                if (diferencia > 900000) 
                {
                    console.log("Alerta!");
                    document.getElementById('prueba').style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                }
            });

Comment: Primero tenes q estar seguro q la condición se este cumpliendo. Se imprime el "Alerta!" ? Segundo que la id que pides en `getElementById ` sea la misma q quieres cambiar

Comment: @manucoBianco la condición si se esta cumpliendo y el id esta tal cual. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Disculpa q tarde en responder. Justo estaba ocupado. Si sigues con el problema podemos migrar esto a una sala de chat aparte, y vemos en profundidad tu caso

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer es capturar el `input` que quieres que cambie de color, puedes asignarle una clase al input, así:

```
var campo=document.getElementsByClassName("color");
```

Luego le asignas el color así;

```
campo.style.backgroundColor="blue";
```